# MongoDB Change index of Array-Element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB-document that looks like:

```
root
   _id: "some-mongo-id",
   title: "MyTitle",
   text:  "My Text",
   contents: [
      0: ...some content object ...,
      1: ...some other object ...,
      2: ...some third object...
      ...
      11: ... some object ...
   ]
```

I want now to change for example to set the index of root.contents[2] to e.g. 7. So I want to resort the array ideally based on the old index and the new position the contents should go.

What is the best approach?

Comment: You want to swap items in the array?

Comment: no. When I have order 1:a 2:b 3:c 4:d 5:e and I get a 1<=>3 change, I want 1 to be placed after the actual 3, e.g. 1:b 2:c 3:a 4:d 5:e

Comment: The way to do this is to retrieve the document, modify the array, and then re-$set the array field to the new array. There's no way to do this with a single update. Why do you want to move elements like this? Perhaps there is a better option that we can discover with more context.

Comment: I think it is important to point out the that "way you **do not** wan't to do it" is by retrieve-modify-save at all costs. So ignore that statement any focus on the latter part which is to explain what you are really trying to do in context in your question. There is likely a better solution when others can see the whole problem.

Comment: I have a document, that is a course and in this course, the user should be able to sort the entries.